# Jupyter lab notebook too big to be opened in browser

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I made a silly choice to execute jupyter notebook using `jupyter nbconvert` command inplace and it generated a lot of image files inside the notebook that it's size grew to >1 GB. Now, I can't open it in browser. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Notebooks are `.json` files behind the scenes, so you can remove the key that corresponds to the output from the dictionary structure.

However, a `>1GB` file will probably be hard to open with any text editor.

If you are using Linux, you can try using the `head` and `tail` commands to get some manageable-sized files and work your way to a reconstructed version of the notebook.

So you would do:

```sh
head -1000 your_notebook.ipynb > head.json
tail -1000 your_notebook.ipynb > tail.json
```

Open both files with a text editor and try to generate from them a `your_notebook_recovered.ipynb` with a correct syntax.

I'm not sure if there is a more automated or fancy way to solve it. This approach is primitive but it saved me from the "giant output" problems various times.